# How should I change the angular routing?

Tags: angularjs

Good evening, I'm writing an application on mobile platform steroids, angular.js and firebase.js. Recently I've faced such problem: the page does not load, because it is trying to access a strange url: `file://file:///Users/patutinskijfedor/Desktop/firebase/WILLY/www/`.

```
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file://file:///Users/patutinskijfedor/Desktop/firebase/WILLY/www/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.
```

I read about this issue in the Internet and realized that my problem is with the routing in Angular. It looks like this (file app.js):

```
angular.module('SCBI', ['SCBI.controllers','ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/teachers',{ templateUrl: 'teachers.html'});
    $routeProvider.when('/teachers/:id', {templateUrl: 't.html', controller: 'TeachersListController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'authorization.html', controller: 'AuthorizationController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

So the problem might be with html5Mode. My question is: how can I fix the routing in app.js? The full code of the project is [here](https://github.com/patut/SCBI).

Comment: you code deactivate the html5 mode if not needed https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: This is covered in gory detail, including some clues about the server implementation, in the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) docs on Angular, as @sam mentions, and also on several blogs. You need to a) not use html5mode, or b) run a server and use URL rewrites.